# Cannot see internal debug print statements from python multiprocessing script

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In the code below I am trying to print out content from a number of urls (dummy urls provided for this example) but I do not see any print statements. This makes it difficult to debug my program. Is there a workaround?

I have already tried setting log levels and enabling verbose mode in python to not much avail - I can see subprocess logs, but these are not informative.

```
import datetime
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import os
import contextlib
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import lxml.html as LH
import lxml.html.clean as clean
import time
from datetime import timedelta
import threading
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import logging
import multiprocessing
import sys

start_time = time.time()
#get all companies from edinet
ignore_tags=('script','noscript','style')

urls = ["https://www.webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone/computers","https://www.webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone/computers/laptops","https://www.webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone/phones/touch"]


allind = list(range(0,len(urls)))

def get_links(inds):
    for ind in inds:
        try:
            l= urls[ind]
            print(l)
            l = l.replace("\n","")
            options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            options.add_argument("headless")
            options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
            driver =  webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/PATH/chromedriver", chrome_options=options)
            driver.get(l)
            content=driver.page_source
            cleaner=clean.Cleaner()
            content=cleaner.clean_html(content)
            print(content)

        except Exception as e:
            sys.stdout.flush()
            print(e)
        driver.quit()


pool = Pool()
mpl = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
mpl.setLevel(multiprocessing.SUBDEBUG)

ITERATION_COUNT = cpu_count()-1
print(ITERATION_COUNT)
count_per_iteration = len(allind) / float(ITERATION_COUNT)
for i in range(0, ITERATION_COUNT):
    print(i)
    list_start = int(count_per_iteration * i)
    list_end = int(count_per_iteration * (i+1))
    pool.apply_async(get_links, [allind[list_start:list_end]])


elapsed_time_secs = time.time() - start_time

msg = "Execution took: %s secs (Wall clock time)" % timedelta(seconds=round(elapsed_time_secs))
print(msg)
```

EDIT :

With the help of the comment below and after some more research I changed the multiprocessing part of the code to the code below and observed expected behavior

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    with Pool(cpu_count()-1) as p:
        p.starmap(get_links, zip(range(1, 400)))
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Comment: You don't even see the output for `print(ITERATION_COUNT)`?

Comment: Printing in multi-processing has its challenges. Use `mpl.<log-level>(message)` instead of `print()`. Where `<log-level>` is `info`, `error`, `debug`... You might want to define `mpl` earlier.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you, but I still don't see logging statements after driver =  webdriver.Chrome... line so I wonder where I need to do anything else. I did define mpl at the beginning of the script.

Comment: You are using `apply_async` without an appropriate blocking call on a returned `AsyncResult` object and you also don't do other things which would prevent your parent from exiting after it started the jobs. You probably just want to use a blocking method like `pool.map` instead of `pool.apply_async` here.